# Change permissions from drwxrwsr-x to drwxrwxr-x

Tags: permissions, file-permissions

When I manually upload plugins in Wordpress using filezilla the sub-folders are created with these permissions drwxrwsr-x

This causes the plugins to failed to be updated automatically.

The correct permissions are drwxrwxr-x

How could I manually change to the correct permissions and how could I prevent this from happening in the first place?

Comment: I would start with `man chmod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On most systems, if a directory’s set-group-ID bit is set, newly created subfiles inherit the same group as the directory, and newly created subdirectories inherit the set-group-ID bit of the parent directory.

With FileZilla, if you right click on a directory you can choose "permissions"
Click it and set as numeric value 775 on your directory. 
Read this [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions) on wordpress for best practices.

> Typically, all files should be owned by your user (ftp) account on your web server, and should be writable by that account. On shared hosts, files should never be owned by the webserver process itself (sometimes this is www, or apache, or nobody user).

[image]

Comment: ok this works.. Also should all plugin files (not directories) be 664 ? Because I can see some plugin files are 755 ..

Comment: @JoannaMikalai 664 would be perfect. Sometimes are 775 because, I think, they are prepared with Windows.